# Accessing member functions of other classes into member function of `this` class using composition or friend classes

Tags: c++, composition, friend-class

I am writing a class using 'composition' as follows -

```
class fibonacci
{
private:
    FibonacciDynamic dy();
    FibonacciRecursive re();
    FibonacciSequential se();
    int count;
public:
    fibonacci(int a):count(a){};
    void disp();
};

void fibonacci::disp()
{
    if(count < 20)
    {
        se.fib();
    }
    else if(count < 50)
    {
        re.fib();
    }
    else
    {
        dy.display();
    }
}
```

Here, `FibonacciDynamic`, `FibonacciRecursive` & `FibonacciSequential` are classes declared in header files. Now, the main problem here is that while using `se.fib()`, `re.fib` & `dy.fib()` functions it gives me error like

`error C2228: left of '.fib' must have class/struct/union`

Is there any other way to use composition approach here without getting above errors?

If not then is it possible to use them as friend classes & access their member functions in a member function of `fibonacci` class?

Thanks.

Comment: "se" should be object . FibonacciSequential se=new FibonacciSequential()

Comment: Thanks. It is useful. I should write default constructors first.

Comment: not Neccessary . Default constructor is neccessary if you are having parameterize constructor in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FibonacciDynamic dy(); is declaration of method FibonacciDynamic fibonacci::dy();

you should remove parentheses to make it data member declaration:

```
...
FibonacciDynamic dy;
...
```